# La différence sémantique entre "social" et "socialiste/socialisme"

Tags: sens, usage, terminologie

[La constitution de la Cinquième République](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_premier_de_la_Constitution_de_la_Cinqui%C3%A8me_R%C3%A9publique_fran%C3%A7aise) déclare que

> La France est une République indivisible, laïque, démocratique et ***sociale***.

(c'est moi qui souligne.)

En anglais les termes *socialist/socialism* sont ambigus : d'un côté la grande partie du public les interprète comme tout ce qui est *social* (par exemple les principes afférents au respect et au soin des autres) et par conséquent des choses bonnes.

D'un autre côté, il faut considérer le sens plus formel de ces termes dans la vie politique et l'histoire, lequel est largement le sens marxiste/communiste du terme, tel qu' il a été officiellement utilisé par [l'URSS et ses satellites](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_des_r%C3%A9publiques_socialistes_sovi%C3%A9tiques) :

> L'Union des Républiques ***Socialistes*** Soviétiques

(c'est encore moi qui souligne.)

Il me semble clair que la France s'identifie comme *une république sociale*, mais pas comme *une république socialiste*. Mais je me pose la question de savoir si ces termes sont également confondus en français - par exemple, *Le parti Socialiste Français*, défend-il les idées marxistes ou plutôt, les idées qui forment la base de la constitution, ou peut-être des idées *socialistes* plus vaguement définies, datant de l'époque pré-communiste ?

**Remarque**
Ce qui m'interesse ici est l'usage (quotidien et soutenu) plutôt que les différences entre la France et les états socialistes ou les tendance politique de la partie socialiste français (celles-là effectivement appartient au [politics.stackexchange.com](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), comme noté dans le commentaires.)

Comment: Hello. Peut-être je ne comprends pas bien le lien de la question avec FSE. Il existe aussi https://politics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Dimitris la question est sur le sens en français de termes *sociale* et *socialiste*. Signifient-ils des choses differentes ?

Comment: @RogerVadim ces termes sont polysémiques et ont varié au cours du temps. Je suis de l'avis de Dimitris, difficile d'en parler sans faire de l'histoire et de la philosophie politiques. Ce n'est peut-être pas hors sujet, mais long à résumer. Ceci dit, la constitution de la Vè est une charnière très intéressante entre socialisme et social (voir les discours de 1948 de De Gaulle à ce sujet).

Comment: @guillaume31 je parle de l'usage (quotidien et soutenu) plutôt que de la différénce entre la France et les états socialistes... comme *une pomme de terre* vs. *une patate* vs. *une patate douce*. C'est l'exemple de la partie socialiste que vous perturbe ?

Comment: Beaucoup de choses me perturbent : la différenciation avec l'anglais que je trouve peu justifiée (sauf à assumer l'insulte moqueuse qu'est devenue *socialist* et à la retourner pour en faire une bonne chose, mais bon), les questions d'histoire politique inévitablement tapies derrière une question de terminologie, etc. :)

Comment: @guillaume31 Le terme *socialisme* me perturbe, car j'ai passé mon enfance en URSS. Comprendre le sens precis de ce terme dans le pays ou je vive maintenant est important pour moi :)

Answer (score 2):

Oui, bien que le deuxième dérive du premier, *social* est *socialiste* sont des adjectifs aux sens bien distincts.

Le premier a trait à la société (ou à une société en particulier), le deuxième est relatif à une doctrine, le socialisme, qui est marquée politiquement.

On parle par exemple de *siège social*, d'*œuvres sociales* ou de *sécurité sociale*, termes qu'on ne peut absolument pas remplacer par *siège socialiste*, *œuvres socialistes* ou *sécurité socialiste*.

L'adjectif *socialiste* lui-même a aussi un sens beaucoup plus modéré et distinct de l'adjectif *communiste* que ces mêmes adjectifs lorsqu'ils étaient employés dans les "pays de l'est" ou même que *socialist* tel qu'il est compris aux États-Unis. En Europe de l'ouest, au cours du XX<sup>e</sup> s., le socialisme s'est peu à peu approché des courants sociaux-démocrates. On est très loin de la "dictature du prolétariat".

Answer (score 1):

De nos jours, [socialiste](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/socialiste) signifie : qui se rapporte au socialisme - le (ou les) courants politiques.

Dans le contexte d'une constitution, on devine qu'il peut être impensable pour les rédacteurs (ou indispensable dans le cas de l'URSS ?) d'arrimer le droit du pays à une idéologie politique en particulier.

Si on parle de la différence entre "République sociale" et "République socialiste", ça me parait alors basculer complètement dans le domaine de l'histoire et de la philosophie politique plutôt que de la langue française.